# How to optimize this script?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages, memory

fx8350, 16Gb ram
just need to solve this:
[image]

13, 19, 19, 16, 26, 33, 26, 31, 5, 24, 21, 34, 35, 35, 35, 20, 7, 12,
18, 17, 6, 8, 15, 24, 2, 17, 15, 22, 29, 15, 21

Comment: Please post actual code not images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica runs out of memory for this code. This sequence is simply too long and too disordered for `FindSequenceFunction` to work. Try `InterpolatingPolynomial` for fit functions if you want.
[image]